# How to pass a constructor reference for parameterised lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method looks like this.

```java
static void doSomething(Function<Irrelevant, Some> supplier) {
}
```

When I try to do this,

```java
doSomething((i) -> new Some()); // i is irrelevant
```

it works. But when I try to do this,

```java
doSomething((i) -> Some::new); // compiler -> bad return type in lambda expression
```

it doesn't.

Is this normal? Is there any way that I can pass a constructor reference for a parameterised function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor with no parameters would be a `Supplier<Some>` and thus it is incompatible with a method asking for a `Function<Irrelevant, Some>`.

Your lambda in `doSomething((i) -> Some::new)` would actually take some element and return a reference to that constructor, i.e. a `Supplier<Some>`, *not* that `Some` itself. You were probably looking for `doSomething(Some::new)` -- but as I said, this will not work either since the constructor does not match the method's parameter (it *would* work, if the constructor had a parameter of type `Irrelevant`).

If the parameter is *really* irrelevant, then you could change the method's signature to

```
static void doSomething(Supplier<Some> supplier) {
```

If that's not possible, your approach with `doSomething((i) -> new Some());` is perfectly fine.